# Getting one or zero elements of QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django

In Django 3.1, suppose I have some model `M`, and I have a `QuerySet` over `M` that I expect has either one or zero elements.  How do I branch on whether it is one or zero elements (throwing an exception if it has two or more), and in the branch with one element, how do I get the one `M` object:

```
try:
    my_query_set = M.objects.filter(some_filter_expr)
    if ???:
        m = ??? # the one M object
    else:
        on_zero_objects()
except ???:
    more_than_one_object()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) to check if there is any data exists in `my_queryset`, if yes, then use [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) to get the one object. If there is multiple objects, then it will raise [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) error. In except block, you can handle it with `more_than_one_object`.

```
my_query_set = M.objects.filter(some_filter_expr)
try:
    if my_query_set.exists()
        m = my_query_set.get()
    else:
        on_zero_objects()
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    more_than_one_object()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`.first()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) (or [`last()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#last) )

```
one_or_none = M.objects.filter(some_filter_expr).first()
```

Thus, the variable `one_or_none` will have either an instance of model `M` or `None`

---

You can handle the ***more than mone element*** condition or separate conditions are in the following way,

```
my_query_set = M.objects.filter(some_filter_expr)
try:
    my_query_set[1]
    handle_more_than_one_element()
except IndexError:
    try:
        my_query_set[0]
        handle_only_one_element()
    except IndexError:
        handle_no_element()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.get()` to get a single element, and handle the exceptions for the `DoesNotExist` case and `MultipleObjectsReturned` cases.

```
from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned

...

try:
    model_object = M.objects.get(some_filter_expr)
except M.DoesNotExist:
     on_zero_objects()
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
     more_than_one_object()
```